# Is it possible to make a console wait on another child process?

Tags: windows, winapi, console-application

Usually when a program is run from the Windows console, the console will wait for the process to exit and then print the prompt and wait for user input. However, if the process starts a child process, the console will still only wait for the first process to exit. It will not wait for the child as well.

Is there a way for the program to get the console to wait on another child process instead of (or as well as) the current process.

I would assume it's impossible because presumably the console is waiting on the process' handle and there's no way to replace that handle. However, I'm struggling to find any confirmation of this.

Comment: think *conhost.exe* exit when last process attached to it exit. so if child will be console app - *conhost.exe* wait for it too

Comment: Sure but I mean when the process exits, the cmd prompt will print the prompt and wait for user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way for the program to get the console to wait on another child process instead of (or as well as) the current process.

No. As you noted, as soon as the 1st process the console creates has exited, the console stops waiting. It has no concept of any child processes being created by that 1st process.

So, what you can do instead is either:

- simply have the 1st process wait for any child process it creates before then exiting itself.
- if that is not an option, then create a separate helper process that creates a [Job Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects) and then starts the main process and [assigns it to that job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/jobapi2/nf-jobapi2-assignprocesstojobobject). Any child processes it creates will automatically be put into the same job as well <sup>1</sup>. The helper process can then [wait for all processes in the job to exit](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130405-00/?p=4743) before then exiting itself. Then, you can have the console run and wait on the helper process rather than the main process.

  <sup>1: by default - a process spawner can choose to break out a new child process from the current job, if the job is setup to allow that.</sup>