# Prevent Win32 standard programs exit immediately

Tags: python, c++, windows, cmd, process

When I launch Windows programs out of cmd, some of them launched kinda like in background and I cannot wait on them:

```sh
# exit at once, and wait does not work for calc.exe and for 32-bit mstsc.exe:
start /wait calc
start /wait C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mstsc.exe
```

This leads to the problem that when I launch these processes using Python `p = subprocess.Popen()` or C++ `QProcess::start()`, these processes finish at once, so `p.wait()` returns / `QProcess::finished()` is emitted at once, and so I cannot wait on these processes to finish (i.e., I would like to wait till the user closes the app window, to get the exit code, and to do some further stuff).

---

At the same time, other programs allow you to wait on them and so can be used with `subprocess.Popen()` or C++ `QProcess::start()` conveniently, so that you could wait on their finish:

```sh
# wait works for 64-bit mstsc.exe and we wait till we close the app window:
start /wait C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe
```

I have found I think two related questions:

- [Is it possible to make a console wait on another child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68543856/is-it-possible-to-make-a-console-wait-on-another-child-process)
- [Possible to have Win32 application block until it exits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961139/possible-to-have-win32-application-block-until-it-exits)

---

I have some questions:

1). Do I understand right that the difference in the behavior of the applications (`32-bit mstsc.exe` and `calc.exe` - **vs** - `64-bit mstsc.exe`) is due to the fact that `32-bit mstsc` and `calc` launch a child process and the parent process does not wait on it and just exits (I concluded this from the first link)? Or is it connected to some other concept? I am not very good acquainted with Windows processes.

2). Is there any way to fix this easily? I mean, the thing is that I need to start `mstsc` as a process  and wait till it's finished. And I discovered that for x64 bit everything works great, but for 32-bit, the `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mstsc.exe` is called and it exits immediately with zero exit code, while the mstsc window does still works (till I close it by mouse). By the second link, it is suggested to use a [Job Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/job-objects). Will it help in my situation or it is not my case? Or maybe is there a simpler way?

3). Also, it's strange that the same program -- `mstsc` -- works differently for 32 and 64 bits build. Does it mean that their source code is different? I honestly expected it to be the same just compiled for different architectures. Though maybe this presumption is very wrong -- I am not sure how different win32 and win64 are.

---

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code on Python launching 32-bit mstsc. This is executed **before** I close the mstsc gui-window:

```py
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen("C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mstsc.exe")
>>> p.wait()
0
>>>
```

Comment: In C++ with WinAPI, yes , that's possible if you launch via WinAPI. In python they are launched thus way through separate shell - priblematic. You need to know what process to watch and shell isn't it.

Comment: So it will be enough to use CreateProcess (AFAIK) and I will not have to use any special Job Objects etc.?

Comment: syswow64\mstsc.exe launches system32\mstsc.exe and exits, so everything is working as expected.

Comment: @Luke Thank you for the insight! How do you know this? Where can I get this info? So it means that if the app is launched on a real 32-bit Windows, everything will work great? I mean my c++ Qt app will be able to wait on it (i.e. to wait and get notified when the user closes mstsc)?

Comment: @Luke I have just guessed that I can check it via Task Manager. There I saw that indeed 64-bit mstsc is running. Is it how you knew it ?